# create a specific directory within each directory in bash

Tags: bash, rhel5, mkdir

We're running an application on RHEL and it is trying to write a mysterious log file to a directory that doesn't exist.  I'm trying to determine a find command that could go through each sub-directory in development and `mkdir log` without creating a recursive indefinite loop in the process.  So if my folder structure from a very basic redacted view was similar to:

```
-dir1
--dir11
--dir12
-dir2
--dir21
--dir22
-dir3
--dir31
--dir32
```

I would want the end result to be

```
-dir1
--dir11
---log
--dir12
---log
--log
-dir2
--dir21
---log
--dir22
---log
--log
-dir3
--dir31
---log
--dir32
---log
--log
```

what bash command could create this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your top-level directory is /development:

```
find /development -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mkdir {}/log
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case, I just found out that `find -type d -not -name log -exec mkdir {}/log \;` also worked for me.